# How to return text from Native (C++) code

Tags: c#, c++, string, pinvoke

I am using Pinvoke for Interoperability between Native(C++) code and Managed(C#) code. What i want to achieve is get some text from native code into my managed code. For this i try lot lot of things,e.g passing string/stringbuilder by ref, using [IN] and [OUT], Marshaling to LPSTR, returning string from function etc. but nothing works in my case. Any help with some small code would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I'd do it with a `BSTR` since it means you don't have to call into native twice per string, once to get the length and then once to get the contents.

With a `BSTR` the marshaller will take care of deallocating the `BSTR` with the right memory manager so you can safely pass it out of your C++ code.

**C++**

```
#include <comutil.h>
BSTR GetSomeText()
{
    return ::SysAllocString(L"Greetings from the native world!");
}
```

**C#**

```
[DllImport(@"test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
private static extern string GetSomeText();
```

There is one minor drawback of the `BSTR`, namely that it carries a UTF-16 payload but your source data may well be `char*`.

To overcome this you can wrap up the conversion from `char*` to `BSTR` like this:

```
BSTR ANSItoBSTR(const char* input)
{
    BSTR result = NULL;
    int lenA = lstrlenA(input);
    int lenW = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, input, lenA, NULL, 0);
    if (lenW > 0)
    {
        result = ::SysAllocStringLen(0, lenW);
        ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, input, lenA, result, lenW);
    } 
    return result;
}
```

That's the hardest one out of the way, and now it's easy to add other wrappers to convert to `BSTR` from `LPWSTR`, `std::string`, `std::wstring` etc.

Comment: @rturrado Many thanks indeed for your corrections in the edit.

Comment: the answer is very helpful, so it deserves it. BTW, just realising that 'may well char*' is missing a 'be'.

Comment: You can pass `-1` as the fourth argument to `MultiByteToWideChar` to have the function calculate the length of the string automatically; avoids the need to call `lstrlenA` yourself.

Comment: The source data type `char*` says nothing about the encoding of the string; if it's an UTF-8 encoded string, consider using `CP_UTF8` instead of `CP_ACP`.

Comment: @Frerich That is a good point. My answer was written under the assumption that text on Windows is almost always encoded using the local ANSI codepage, or UTF-16. UTF-8 is quite rarely seen in Windows.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/c6914388-3544-49c7-a6ca-a0dd69aa993c/) is a topic where string marshaling has been discussed.

It's needed to mark parameter with attribute

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPSTR)]
```

Comment: Worked for me on Unity for Android.

Comment: This type of marshaling also goes by the name *"memory leak"*.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of doing this through C#. I am calling Native function `GetWindowText` through C# by pInvoking. `GetWindowText` returns the caption of the window whose `handle` is passed to it.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

    public static string GetText(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        // Allocate correct string length first
        int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
        GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
        return sb.ToString();
    }        

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = GetText(this.Handle);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning a `char *`, and don't want to have to modify the C/C++ code to allocate memory for your return value (or you can't modify that code), then you can change your C# extern function-prototype to return an `IntPtr`, and do the marshaling yourself.

For instance, here's a snippet of the interop I wrote for [Pocketsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/):

```
[DllImport("sphinxbase.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr /* char const * */ jsgf_grammar_name(IntPtr /* jsgf_t * */ jsgf);
```

And here's the get-accessor for the C# `JsgfGrammar` class. `m_pU` is an `IntPtr` that points to the raw `jsgf_t` object.

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        IntPtr pU = jsgf_grammar_name(m_pU);
        if (pU == IntPtr.Zero)
            strName = null;
        else
            strName = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pU);
        return strName;
    }
}
```

Modifying this example for other string formats (e.g. Unicode) should be trivial.

Comment: Who's going to clean up the resources (potentially) allocated in native code now?

Comment: @IInspectable: The native code owns the resources referred to by the IntPtr. Any cleanup would have to be done there, regardless of whether C# interop is involved.

Comment: *"Any cleanup would have to be done there"* - Obviously. The more difficult question would then be: When? The marshaler isn't going to call back into native code to let it know: *"That pointer you handed out earlier? I've made a copy of the pointee. Feel free to release those resources on your end. Just letting you know."* Who's going to inform the native code to let go?

Comment: @IInspectable: Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi() makes a copy of the C-string referred to by the IntPtr, converting it to a C# string, so your concern isn't applicable here.

Comment: *"Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi() makes a copy of the C-string referred to by the IntPtr"* - Which is exactly what I said. `PtrToStringAnsi()` then forgets the `IntPtr`, leaving the native code as the sole owner. Said native code never gets informed that it can release the resource. This is called a *"memory leak"*.

Comment: @IInspectable: There's no reason for the native code to free the original IntPtr once it's been converted to a C# string; the return value of jsgf_grammar_name() doesn't involve an allocation. If it did, then it would be on the C# interop code to free it, e.g. Marshal.FreeHGlobal() or Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(), depending on how it was allocated, but in my experience, such an API is pretty rare. Instead, the C++ objects/memory persist until something happens in the normal course of C++ program flow, and the C# interop is merely an inspector/facade.

Comment: *"the return value of jsgf_grammar_name() doesn't involve an allocation"* - This question isn't asking about this particular library. It's asking the generic question, and in the general case, this is a memory leak. At the very least you will want to document the constraints for this proposed solution. Though, really, handing out a `BSTR` is all-around better (as illustrated in David's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5308793/1889329)). There's value in using types that understand (transfer of) ownership.

Comment: @IInspectable: It's not a memory leak in the interop case unless it's a memory leak when called from C/C++. And the API would have to document that the caller is responsible for freeing memory, which from the C# interop point of view, would be the C# interop itself. Fortunately, such APIs are rare, and are generally wrapped with smart-pointer objects.

Comment: *"And the API would have to document that the caller is responsible for freeing memory, which from the C# interop point of view, would be the C# interop itself."* - Right. And this proposed solution doesn't even acknowledge this. *"Fortunately, such APIs are rare, and are generally wrapped with smart-pointer objects."* - C++ smart pointers are **entirely** useless in this scenario.

Comment: @IInspectable: My proposed solution doesn't acknowledge this because it's an extremely rare case, and it's assumed the reader is lucid enough to take such a rare case into account. And smart pointers *are* useful, for there is no reason a C++ smart-pointer can't be brought into C# interop's realm, and deleted from there in an interop class' destructor and `Dispose()` method. But again, in my experience, justifying that would involve really rare usage cases, and even then, would probably be overkill.

Answer (score -2):

why not building your own text struct :

```
struct mystr { mystr(const char *_) : _text((_ == 0) 
                                           ? 0 
                                           : ::strdup(_)
                                          ) 
                                      {}
              ~mystr() { if(this->_text != 0) delete [] this->_text; }
               operator char * & () { return this->_text; }

              private : char *_text;
             };
```