# Delphi 7 DLL to be called from Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, dll, interface, delphi-7, delphi-xe2

I need to wrap some legacy code in Delphi 7 for use within Delphi XE2.  My question seems simple, but I tried ALL the examples I could find and they all fail.  Basically, I need to be able to pass strings between D7 and DXE2, and as far as I can figure out, the safest approach is to use pchar (since I do not want to ship the borlandmm dll).
So DLL written in D7, to be called by Delphi XE2

My interface needs to be

IN My DLL:

```
function d7zipFile(pFatFile,pThinFile : PChar) : integer; stdCall;
function d7unzipfile(pThinFile,pFatFile : PChar) : integer; stdCall;
```

I need to pass BACK the pFatFile name in the unzipfile function.

In My calling code:

```
function d7zipFile(pFatFile,pThinFile : PChar) : integer; external 'd7b64zip.dll';

function d7unzipfile(pThinFile,pFatFile : PChar) : integer; external 'd7b64zip.dll';
```

Could someone please assist with the best way to implement these?

Obviously I am not looking for the actual zip/unzip code - I have that working fine within D7. I want to know how to declare and work with the string / pchar params, since the various types I tried (PWideChar, WideString, ShortString etc) all give errors.

So I would be happy to simply be able to do a showMessage in the d7zipFile function for both filenames.
And then be able to do a showMessage in delphiXE2 on the pFatFile variable, which means the strings went both ways OK?

Comment: You're evidently able to change the D7 code, so why not do the whole thing in XE?

Comment: Change `PChar` in the calling code to *PAnsiChar* and fix the omitted calling convention (**stdcall**) to resync with the D7 prototypes.

Comment: I think I'd use WideString here. Make it a var param if the DLL has to return a value. That saves you having to allocate in the caller when you don't know the length.

Comment: On the other hand, XE2 comes with an excellent ZIP component so perhaps you can do away with the DLL

Answer (score 7):

By far the easiest way to do this is to use `WideString`. This is the Delphi wrapper around the COM `BSTR` type. Dynamic allocation of the string payload is done using the shared COM allocator. Since the Delphi RTL manages that, it is transparent to you.

In the Delphi 7 code you declare your functions like this:

```
function d7zipFile(const FatFile, ThinFile: WideString): integer; stdcall;
function d7unzipfile(const ThinFile: WideString; var FatFile: WideString): 
    integer; stdcall;
```

In your calling code you declare the functions like this:

```
function d7zipFile(const FatFile, ThinFile: WideString): integer; stdcall; 
    external 'd7b64zip.dll';
function d7unzipfile(const ThinFile: WideString; var FatFile: WideString): 
    integer; stdcall; external 'd7b64zip.dll';
```

---

The alternative to this approach is to use `PAnsiChar` or `PWideChar`. Note that you cannot use `PChar` because that alias refers to different types depending on which version of Delphi you use. In Delphi 7 `PChar` is an alias for `PAnsiChar`, and in XE2 it is an alias for `PWideChar`.

The big downside of using `PAnsiChar`, say, is that the caller needs to allocate the string which is returned from the DLL. But typically the caller does not know how large that string needs to be. There are a variety of solutions to the problem but the neatest approach is always to use a shared allocator. You state that you do not want to rely on `borlandmm.dll` and so the next most obvious common allocator is the COM allocator. And that's why `WideString` is attractive.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Does the WideString approach work with other programming languages?

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff Mostly yes it does. It's just a COM BSTR. But there is a trap if you try to use a `WideString` as a function return value because Delphi's semantics for return values are not compatible with the ABI used by many other common Windows implementations of languages like C, C++, C# etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349530/why-can-a-widestring-not-be-used-as-a-function-return-value-for-interop

Comment: +1 Since WideString is a good candidate for easy string process, managing the Unicode content even on older Delphi revision. You may emphasize about the `var` parameter description for `FatFile`, which is the main solution about OP's problems: pass *back* a string content.