# exporting C++ dll to Delphi program

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I have a dll with exporting function

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) IDriver * __stdcall GetDriver()
```

There is a programm which is written on Delphi. It can't see the function GetDriver(). 
It's double awful because I can not get and modify sources of this program.

What may be the reason of successful loading my dll (according log file) and failed call exporting function? Thank you.

Window 7 x64, Visual Studio 2010, C++ project for x86 target

Comment: is this declaration from .h file or .cpp file ? do declarations from those files match letter to letter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the function will have been exported with a decorated name. I'd expect it to have been exported with the name `GetDriver@0`. So you could import it like this:

```
function GetDriver: IDriver; stdcall; external 'DllName.dll' name 'GetDriver@0';
```

Use a tool like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check the exact name used to export the function.

If you cannot modify the Delphi code, then you'll need to make your C++ DLL match. Do that by using a .def file which allows you control over the exported name.

---

The other problem you will face is that Delphi's ABI for return values differs from that used by most other tools on the Windows platform. Specifically a return value is semantically a `var` parameter. On the other hand, your C++ compiler will regard the return value as an `out` parameter. My question on [Delphi `WideString` return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349530/why-can-a-widestring-not-be-used-as-a-function-return-value-for-interop) covers exactly this issue.

Because of this, I'd expect the function declaration above to lead to access violations. Instead you should declare the return value to be a `Pointer` and cast it to an interface reference in your Delphi code. You'll need to double check and make sure that the reference counting is handled appropriately.

Again, if you cannot modify the Delphi code, you need to make the C++ code match. A Delphi interface return value is implemented as an [additional `var` parameter following the other parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Program_Control#Handling_Function_Results). So, to make your C++ function match, declare it like this:

```
void __stdcall GetDriver(IDriver* &retVal);
```

Comment: Checking export table would never harm, yet how can he end with mangled name after specifying `extern "C"` ?

Comment: @Arioch'The It's not a mangled name. It's a decorated name. `extern "C"` suppresses mangling, but does not suppress decoration.

Comment: @David Heffernan Thank you for answering.  
I can't access to Delpi code. The exporting function GetDriver() returns pointer to the object. Do you mean that I need return this pointer as out parameter of function?

Comment: @Myosotis If you can't change the Delphi program then you are stuck with how it is. I think you may have problems, but I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: @David there is a difference? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C_name_decoration_in_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: Delphi program collapses when my dll returns pointer. 100% problem %))
Anyway thank you a lot, @David Heffernan

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes, there is a difference.

Comment: @Myosotis I'll update the answer to help you out. I think I can solve it.