# C++ consuming delphi DLL

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, widestring

I'm not able to use the function of a dll developed in delphi. I'm having some difficulties with the conversions of types.

This is the function I want to call the DLL:

```
function rData(ID: Cardinal; queue: WideString): WideString; stdcall;
```

My code in C++ was so:

```
typedef string (*ReturnDataSPL)(DWORD, string);

string result;
HMODULE hLib;
hLib = LoadLibrary("delphi.dll");
pReturnDataSPL = (ReturnDataSPL)GetProcAddress(hLib,"rData");
if (NULL != pReturnDataSPL)
   result = pReturnDataSPL(JobID,printerName);
```

The problem I'm not able to make it work. I do not know which type is compatible with Delphi WideString and Cardinal.

Someone help me

> **EDIT:**
>
> This is the function I want to call the DLL:
>
> ```
> procedure rData(ID: Cardinal; queue: WideString; var Result: WideString); stdcall;
> ```
>
> *After changing the code looked like this:*
>
> ```
> typedef void (__stdcall *ReturnDataSPL)(DWORD, BSTR, BSTR&);
>
> HMODULE hLib;
> BSTR result = NULL;
> hLib = LoadLibrary("delphi.dll");
>
> pReturnDataSPL = (ReturnDataSPL)GetProcAddress(hLib,"rData");
> if (NULL != pReturnDataSPL)
> {
>    pReturnDataSPL(JobID,(BSTR)"Lexmark X656de (MS) (Copiar 2)",result);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've got very little chance of calling that function.

For a start your current code can't hope to succeed since I presume `string` is `std::string`. That's a C++ data type which Delphi code cannot either provide or consume. To match up against Delphi's `WideString` you need to use the COM `BSTR` data type.

Another problem with your code as it stands is that it uses `cdecl` in the C++ side, and `stdcall` on the Delphi side. You'll need to align the calling conventions.

However, that will also fail because of a difference between Delphi's ABI for return values, and the platform standard. That topic was covered in detail here: [Why can a WideString not be used as a function return value for interop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349530/why-can-a-widestring-not-be-used-as-a-function-return-value-for-interop)

Your best bet is to stop using `WideString` as a return value and convert it into a C++ reference parameter. You'll want to convert the Delphi to match.

You are looking at something like this:

**Delphi**

```
procedure rData(ID: Cardinal; queue: WideString; var Result: WideString); stdcall;
```

**C++**

```
typedef void (__stdcall *ReturnDataSPL)(DWORD, BSTR, BSTR&);
```

Comment: I changed the code as above:
But when the function is executed I get an exception:
'Unhandled exception at 0x772b15ee in CallbackSample.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.'

what can it be?
Thank you

Comment: Your C++ code doesn't match mine. Third parameter must be passed by reference. Compare the difference between your code and mine. Also, you can't just cast a BSTR into existence. You've got to make a real BSTR!

Comment: SysAllocString to make a BSTR. Or use one of the BSTR convenience wrappers.

Comment: Good. Remember to free your BSTRs.

Comment: I would make use of the `WideString` class in the C++ code to manage the BSTR memory. For the second parameter, you can use `WideString::c_bstr()` to pass a BSTR value to the function. For the third parameter, I would change its declaration to `BSTR*` and then use `WideString`'s overridden `&` operator to pass a `BSTR*` to the function, eg: `typedef void (__stdcall *ReturnDataSPL)(DWORD, BSTR, BSTR*); WideString result; pReturnDataSPL(JobID, WideString("Lexmark X656de (MS) (Copiar 2)").c_bstr(), &result);`

Comment: @Remy WideString is not available in most C++ compilers. Only in the very rarely seen Embarcadero compiler. Until stated otherwise I'm assuming the common compilers, MSVC or GNU.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Other compilers have similar classes available, like `_bstr_t` or `CComBSTR`.

Comment: @remy yep, that's what I meant in an earlier comment