# Calling a Delphi method in a dll from c#

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

I am trying to call a method in a Delphi DLL with the following signature:

```
 function SMap4Ovr(const OverFileName       : ShortString    ;
                    const Aclay              : Integer        ;
                    const Acarbon            : Double         ;
                    out   errstr             : ShortString): WordBool;
```

I am using the following import in C#:

```
        [DllImport("SMap.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern bool SMap4Ovr(
        string OverFileName,
        int Aclay,
        double Acarbon,
        out string errstr
        );
```

But I am getting a AccessViolationException.

I seem to be able to call into a couple of simpler methods in the DLL that have string parameters but not ints or doubles.

I have also tried with the CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl but this gives me the same error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When writing interop code it is critical that both sides of the interface match in every way. Here are the main issues that you must make agree on both sides:

1. Calling conventions.
2. Parameters lists.
3. Parameter types and semantics.

The first observation is that your calling conventions do not match. You have `register` on the Delphi side and `stdcall` on the C# side. The Delphi `register` convention is private to Delphi and so you should use `stdcall`.

Secondly, your string parameter types do not match. The Delphi `shortstring` is a data type that became legacy when Delphi 2 was released and should be considered a relic from the previous century. It was never a valid interop type, and there's nothing in the p/invoke framework that can be used to match it. Whilst you could attempt to do the marshalling by hand, this is a lot of work that is simply not needed when there are simple solutions available. You should try to forget all about `shortstring`.

You need to use a string type that both sides of the interface can work with. You could use null-terminated C strings, but a better and simpler choice is the COM `BSTR` which is `WideString` in Delphi.

So, the final result is as follows.

**Delphi**

```
function SMap4Ovr(
    OverFileName: WideString;
    Aclay: Integer;
    Acarbon: Double;
    out errstr: WideString
): WordBool; stdcall;
```

**C#**

```
[DllImport("SMap.dll")]
public static extern bool SMap4Ovr(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] 
    string OverFileName,
    int Aclay,
    double Acarbon,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] 
    out string errstr
);
```

I did not bother specifying the calling convention on the `DllImport` since the default is `stdcall`. If you prefer you can be explicit about this.

Be careful when using `WideString` that you [don't attempt to use it as a return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349530/why-can-a-widestring-not-be-used-as-a-function-return-value-for-interop). Because Delphi uses non-standard semantics for return values, you can only use simple types that fit into a register as return values.

Comment: Thanks David that was a great help.

Comment: I solved my problem with this post. +1 MarshalAs did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Default calling convention in Delphi is register, not stdcall. It seems [calling conventions details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) show us that Microsoft fastcall is not the same as Borland fastcall (register)

And C# string type differs from Delphi ShortString (it contains internally one byte length + string body)

Comment: `fastcall` is indeed different from `register`, and in any case not supported by the pinvoke marshaller