Request for permission of type System.DirectoryServices failed
Getting issue like

Request for permission of type "System.DirectoryServices.. 4.0.0.0' failed

while running a web application from VS IDE in a server owned by our team when LDAP code gets executed. Similarly, when oracle connection initialisation code is called, System.Security.Permission error is occurring. Target framework version is .NET 4.5
Tried setting trust level to Full and without it as well in app web.config. AllowOverride is set to true only in web.config under respective .NET framework's Config folder. I need proper steps to troubleshoot the root cause of these issues.

Questions like this usually require the complete error message (full call stack if that's included), not just part of it. Please edit the question to include such key information.

Make sure your app's Application Pool is using the same permission of the old server's.

Your code doesn't run with sufficient permissions.
Update the user that is used in hosting your web application and have it have the right to do this.
As per comment this doesn't work for web applications
Add a Manifest file and set the app to be admin mode:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>


Thanks. May I know whether this only applies to windows app as the link says ? Please note that mine is a web application and it works fine in the old windows server but due to EoSL we're working on migrating the app to new server. Facing this issue in new server only

UAC settings are not helpful for web apps like the other comment said.

@PaulsonMaclean, I am not sure; I thought that System.DirectoryService was a Windows only thing. If you need an other operating system, then you should test if the LDAP (if they use LDAP) query states the user is in an elevated role.
You could write a Delphi wrapper and call the Delphi wrapper as Delphi will work every ware and you can call a Delphi dll from .net (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601423/calling-a-delphi-method-in-a-dll-from-c-sharp/78284888#78284888)

The new server is also a windows server

@PaulsonMaclean, the user in the application pool and the on the site should be the same and that user needs to have the permission
