# PInvokeStackImbalance when calling Delphi dll function

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke, dllimport, delphi-xe5

A (non-COM) Delphi dll has a function being exported:

```
function GetQuestions(Digit1, Digit2: string; CountryISO: string):string;
```

I have added this dll as an existing item in Visual Studio 2012 and have set its *Build Action* to *None*, *Copy to Output Directory* to *Copy Always*.

The class containing the `DllImportAttribute`:

```
public class RefundLibrary
{
    [DllImport("RefundLibrary.dll", EntryPoint = "GetQuestions", 
        CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetQuestions(string digit1, string digit2, 
        string countryISO);
}
```

When I call this method in the `Page_Load` of a WebForm (not sure if relevant), it throws a `PInvokeStackImbalance` for a possible signature mismatch on the below indicated line:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr str = RefundLibrary.GetQuestions("", "", "BE"); //<- here
    string result = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(str);

    testp.InnerText = result;
}
```

I also tried to change the DllImport method's return type to string, the error is identical.

I figure the `Marshal.PtrToStringUni(str)` is correct as far as the [Embarcadero docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/String_Types_(Delphi)) go?

> In RAD Studio, string is an alias for UnicodeString

Is this really a signature mismatch? What am I missing (except, obviously, a decent understanding of P/Invoke)?

Comment: Are you sure it's StdCall? Imbalance usually happens when that should be cdecl.

Comment: Also, I don't think you can import Delphi functions with signatures that use Delphi String arguments in .NET and expect it to Just Work. Delphi strings are RTL-managed structures, with special memory handling, reference counting, and so on.

Comment: @plinth setting CallingConvention.Cdecl doesn't change anything.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I also attempted [a void method with an out param instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9353800/1226915) but then I just get an AccessViolation so I'm pretty sure that isn't it either (although I've used this approach before with COM dll's and there it seems to work)

Comment: Delphi strings are not compatible with anything except Delphi strings. Use PChar (or PAnsiChar) on the Delphi side. You clearly can't return a string, either; your DLL should be receiving a pre-allocated buffer (from .NET you can use a StringBuilder that has capacity allocated) and the buffer size as a parameter and then filling that buffer to return data. (An alternative is to have the .NET side call the function once with a nil buffer; the DLL returns the size of buffer needed. The .NET code then allocates space and passes the proper sized buffer to the DLL in a second call to the function.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call that function. It uses the Delphi only `register` calling convention, and uses Delphi strings. Change it to:

```
procedure GetQuestions(
    Digit1: WideString;
    Digit2: WideString; 
    CountryISO: WideString;
    out Questions: WideString
); stdcall;
```

On the C# side:

```
[DllImport("RefundLibrary.dll")]
public static extern void GetQuestions(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    string digit1,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    string digit2,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] 
    string countryISO,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    out string questions
);
```

The use of `WideString/BStr` is great for the out parameter. Because the content is allocated on the shared COM heap which means that the caller can deallocate it.

You could use `PWideChar/LPWStr` for the input parameters. That would work fine. I used `WideString` because I wanted to be consistent. It's up to you.