# Delphi 2007 EXE and C++ DLL: Debug Output: Heap block at 027D4FF8 modified at 027D5009 past requested size of 9 Process

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, heap-memory

I am trying to execute imported function in Delphi 2007:

```
function getOfficialCardNumber(): WideString ; cdecl; external 'idcapp.dll';
```

but after few second (in debug configuration) it stops here:

```
77BD37D6 C6055562C17700   mov byte ptr [$77c16255],$00
```

and says this:

```
Debug Output: Heap block at 027D4FF8 modified at 027D5009 past requested size of 9  Process PreglediZaDom.exe (23672)
```

Mentioned function was written in C++ (Visual Studio)

I have tried changing WideString to PWideString and others, but no success. Does anyone know what can be a problem?

In similar application, but written in VB6 they gave me this function to convert strings:

```
Public Function pisBstrToString(bstr) As String

    Dim bArray()    As Integer

    Dim longArray() As Long

    Dim str         As String

    Dim i           As Integer

    bArray = pisStringToBArray(bstr)
    longArray = pisBArrayToLongArray(bArray)

    str = ""

    For i = 1 To UBound(longArray)

        If longArray(i) > 0 And longArray(i) < 256 Then
            str = str & Chr(longArray(i))
        Else
            str = str & pisLongToUnichar(longArray(i))
        End If

    Next i

    pisBstrToString = str

End Function
```

I know now that function written in C++ was exported like this:

```
BSTR _stdcall getOfficialCardNumber()
```

Comment: Perhaps the translation is wrong? How is the function declared in the C or C++ header? Or how is the function declared in VB6?

Comment: I don't have C++ header (dll was built by someone else).     Public Declare Function getOfficialCardNumber   Lib "C:\WINDOWS\system32\idcapp.dll" () As String is declaration in VB6

Comment: I doubt VB6 can handle `cdecl`, so it should probably be `stdcall`. And the result is probably a `WideString` indeed.

Comment: It has been a long time since I interfaced with VB6, so the following may be wrong: instead of WideString, try PWideChar. And be sure to free the result with SysFreeString.

Comment: FWIW, if people write a DLL (no matter in which language), they should provide a C or C++ header for it. My view on writing DLLs: http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html

Comment: Oh, no, no, please read above text: "I am trying to execute imported function in Delphi 2007:". I only mention that it was working without problems in EXE built in VB6, but Delphi is my concern now. Also I tried with PWideChar too and no luck, code just hangs a while and goes in cpu tab with "mov byte ptr" thing

Comment: Ok, I will ask them for C++ header, thanks

Comment: Did you change the calling convention to stdcall?

Comment: FWIW, going by the VB6 declaration, it is probably WideString or PWideChar. But the problem seems to happen earlier, so perhaps the DLL needs some setup function call first.

Comment: please forget about VB6, we are speaking here about Delphi 2007 application, I already called 3 more functions (before the problematic one) with cdecl and they worked as well, but I will change now to stdcall

Comment: I know that you are not interfacing with VB6, but the only declarations I see is the one for Delphi (which could be wrong) and the one for VB6 (which works). So I try to use the VB6 declaration to find out what the proper Delphi declaration should be. It might also help if you post a little more of the VB6 code (just edit your question) that works.

Answer (score 1):

VB6 does not support `cdecl`, only `stdcall`.  So right there, you are using the wrong calling convention in your Delphi code, causing the call stack to be mismanaged.

Delphi's `WideString` type is a wrapper for a COM `BSTR` string, which VB6 does use for its own strings - but NOT for a `String` return value of a external DLL function!  Even if VB6 expected/accepted a `BSTR` as output, the DLL function would return the `BSTR` pointer in the `EAX` cpu register, like most other return types.  However, Delphi does not use `EAX` when handling `WideString` as a return type. It is passed as a hidden `var` parameter instead.  See 
[Why can a WideString not be used as a function return value for interop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349530/) for more details on that.

If the DLL function returns a `char*` pointer, you will have to declare the function return value as `PAnsiChar`:

```
function getOfficialCardNumber(): PAnsiChar; stdcall; external 'idcapp.dll';
```

Otherwise, if it returns a `wchar_t*` pointer <sup>1</sup>, you will have to declare the function return value as `PWideChar` instead:

```
function getOfficialCardNumber(): PWideChar; stdcall; external 'idcapp.dll';
```

Either way, you have another issue to deal with - who *owns* the memory being pointed at, and how should it be freed?  Delphi can't *directly* free the memory returned by a DLL, so how is the memory allocated?

- If statically within the DLL, it doesn't need to be freed at all.
- If dynamically, which memory manager allocated it?

  - If it is a memory manager that is internal to the DLL, then the DLL must export a separate function to receive the pointer when you are done using it so it can be freed using the same memory manager.
  - If it is an OS-provided memory API (`LocalAlloc()`/`GlobalAlloc()`, `IMalloc.Alloc()imalloc`/`CoTaskMemAlloc()`, etc), then the Delphi code can directly call the corresponding memory-freeing function (`LocalFree()`/`GlobalFree()`, `IMalloc.Free()`/`CoTaskMemFree()`, etc).

---

<sup>1</sup>: if it *happens* to actually be a `BSTR` pointer, you will need to pass the returned pointer to `SysFreeString()` when you are done using it.

Comment: in this dll there is a procedure called login: procedure login(uName, pwd: WideString); cdecl; external 'idcapp.dll'; which if I declare like this: procedure login(uName, pwd: String); cdecl; external 'idcapp.dll'; it will not work, so parameters have to be of WideString type, so I thought that return parameter should be WideString also

Comment: And yes, it stops in EAX register

Comment: `String` <> `WideString` in Delphi. You can't switch them when interop is involved. If the DLL function requires a `WideString`, pass it a `WideString`.  But are you sure it is not actually expecting a `PWideChar` instead? Is the DLL written in Delphi, or something else?

Comment: dll is written in C++ and I don't know anything about what they use as return type, I will ask them for a header tomorrow

Comment: In that case, unless `login()` is declared as accepting a `BSTR` parameter, you should not be declaring it as `WideString` in Delphi. Use `PAnsiChar` for `char*` or `PWideChar` for `wchar_t*` instead. In the latter case, you can use a `WideString` variable, just type-cast it to `PWideChar` when passing it