# Unmanaged exports: Consume C# object in delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, dllimport

I am using the "Unmanaged Exports" library to export functions from a c# class-library. For basic functions with easy signatures this works pretty good. Now I want to export a C# object that my Delphi application wants to work with. The following code compiles:

```
[ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public class Sample
{
    public string Text
    {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        get;
        [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        set;
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string TestMethod()
    {
        return Text + "...";
    }
}

static class UnmanagedExports
{
    [DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)]
    static Object CreateSampleInstance()
    {
        try
        {
            return new Sample { Text = "xy" };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In my Delphi application I want to load the dll via the following code:

```
function CreateSampleInstance(): IDispatch; stdcall; external 'UnmanagedExports.dll';

procedure TForm3.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  disp: IDispatch;
  variant: OleVariant;
begin
  CoInitialize(0);

  disp := CreateSampleInstance();

  variant := disp;

  ShowMessage(variant.TestMethod());
end;
```

I get a null-pointer exception in my Delphi-Code. There must be something wrong with my signatures. Anybody has an idea how to get this working?

Comment: This isn't going to work out. Expose your C# class as a COM object and don't use UnmanagedExports at all

Comment: The following website states it should be possible (at least with IUknown): https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports It sadly doesn't shows how to consume it via Delphi but I guess there must be a way then?

Comment: Why would you bother. COM support from .net is excellent. Use it and it's all good.

Comment: Using COM introduces a lot of complexity. You have to use an installer and you enter the dll-hell at some point.

Comment: I'm using lots of COM calling c# code from Delphi. I also use side by side registration to not need to register the com-server globaly

Comment: Exactly. It's perfectly possible to avoid registration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the example [here](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) more precisely (avoiding IDispatch/dual interface), it works:

c#

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyLibrary
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("8871C5E0-B296-4AB8-AEE7-F2553BACB730"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface ISample
    {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        string GetText();
        void SetText([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]string value);
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        string TestMethod();
    }
    public class Sample : ISample
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string GetText()
        {
            return Text;
        }
        public void SetText(string value)
        {
            Text = value;
        }
        public string TestMethod()
        {
            return Text + "...";
        }
    }
    public static class UnmanagedExports
    {
        [DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static void CreateSampleInstance([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out ISample instance)
        {
            instance = null;
            try
            {
                instance =  new Sample { Text = "Hello, world" };
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

delphi/lazarus

```
type
  ISample = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{8871C5E0-B296-4AB8-AEE7-F2553BACB730}']
    function GetText: WideString; safecall;
    procedure SetText(const Value: WideString); safecall;
    function TestMethod: WideString; safecall;
    property Text: WideString read GetText write SetText;
  end;

procedure CreateSampleInstance(out Sample: ISample); stdcall; external 'MyLibrary.dll';

...
var
  Sample: ISample;
begin
  CreateSampleInstance(Sample);
  Writeln(Sample.Text);
  Writeln(Sample.TestMethod);
  Readln;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it's still crashing. I get an access violation at Sample.TestMethod. Maybe there is something I am missing.

Comment: Are you claiming that the exact code from this answer fails?

Comment: Yes. I copy and pasted it. I am using Delphi XE5 and both DLL and EXE are 32 Bit binaries.

Comment: I used Dependecy Walker to ensure that the DLL export is present. Looks OK.

Comment: The functions that return WideString are can't work ever. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349530/why-can-a-widestring-not-be-used-as-a-function-return-value-for-interop try replacing those with integer and see if that is the problem

Comment: Right. Was trying it with Lazarus initially. Edited answer.

Comment: Works with `safecall` calling convention in both Lazarus and Delphi.

Comment: safecall converts the return value to an out param and makes the actual return value an HRESULT

Comment: Yes, and I think that fits `InterfaceIsIUnknown`.