# char* to a string in C#

Tags: c#, pointers

I'm calling a function from a native DLL which returns a  `char*` pointer, how can I convert the returned pointer to a string ?
I tried :

```
char* c = function();
string s = new string(c);
```

But it just returned a weird Chinese character, which isn't the right value for `c`.

Comment: Make sure that c points to Unicode (UTF-16) data.

Comment: I'm calling a function in a native DLL which returns "hi" as a `char*`. For some reason the converted string isn't "hi".

Comment: You've posted nothing that can be used to help you. "I've got something (but I'm not gonna tell you what it is), and when I do this thing, it's returning something I don't expect (but I'm not telling you that either)." Post the declaration of the external function, the import statement you're using in C#, and the code calling it including variable declarations, and perhaps someone can help. As is, it's really guesswork.

Comment: How do you receive this char*? Is it from an unmanaged (native) DLL that you're calling through P/Invoke? If that's the case, your P/Invoke declaration may be tweaked such that the framework marshaller does this for you. Keep in mind that char* in C# and char* in C/C++ are not the same: char* in C# is really wchar_t* in C++.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Perhaps the native DLL is actually returning an ANSI string instead of a Unicode string. In that case, call `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
string s = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)c);
```

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. And sorry for not giving enough info.

Comment: In my case i need to use little change: Marshal.PtrToStringAuto((IntPtr)c) and than it works.

Answer (score 2):

Update your P/Invoke declaration of your external function as such:

```
[DllImport ( "MyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "Func" )]
[return : MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )]
string Func ( ... );
```

This way you won't have to do extra work after you get the pointer.

Comment: In my case, it didn't work. I had to use the Marshal answer from @michael liu. Your answer was still trying to free up the memory after and it caused issue on the type I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't completely clear, but your comment suggests you're calling into a c++ dll from c#.  You need to return a bstr, not a char * or a string.

I'd start with this question/answer, which I used when I had to perform this operation:

[How to return text from Native (C++) code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308584/how-to-return-text-from-native-c-code)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var charArray = new[] {'t', 'e', 's', 't'};
            fixed (char* charPointer = charArray)
            {
                var charString = new string(charPointer);
            }
        }
```